# how to solve this kind of modular arithmetic problems with exponents?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

What is the method of solving similar problems like given below
$$x^7 \equiv 25\pmod{54}$$

Comment: Take $x=43$ this is the solution

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner The question is not about what the solution is but about the method.

Comment: Hint: $x$ is coprime to $54$ so $x^{18}\equiv 1$ so expt arith is $\!\bmod 18$ so you need only raise both side to power $\,1/7\equiv -5\pmod{18}\,$ yielding $\,x\equiv 25^{-5}\equiv 43,\ $ i.e take the $7$'th root of both sides by raising to power $\,1/7.\ $ The question is a dupe and will likely be closed as such.

Answer (score 1):

First solve $x^7\equiv25\bmod27$ as follows.

Note that $x^{18}\equiv1\bmod27$ by Euler's theorem, so

$x^7\equiv-2\bmod27\implies (x^7)^{13}\equiv x^{91}\equiv (x^{18})^5x\equiv x\equiv(-2)^{13}\bmod 27.$

Now $2^5=32\equiv5\bmod27$, so $2^{10}\equiv25\equiv-2\bmod27,$ so $x\equiv(-2)^{13}\equiv2\times8\equiv16\bmod 27.$

To have $x^7\equiv25\bmod 54$, we also need $x\equiv1 \bmod2$.  Can you take it from here?

Comment: I also know $2^{10}\equiv25\bmod27$ because I know $27|999$ and $2^{10}=1024$

Comment: You can also note 25 is a square so $x$ must be, as 7 is odd.

Comment: I could have said $\bmod 27:  x^7\equiv5^2\implies x\equiv(x^7)^{13}\equiv ((5)^2)^{13}\equiv5^{26}\equiv5^8\equiv(5^2)^4\equiv(-2)^4\equiv16$