# How to Solve $x^7=4 \pmod{81}$ without Guessing?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I found this question in my book but got no idea on how to approach it.

> 1. Find one x that solves: $x^7=4(mod 81)$
> 2. How many different x's between 1 and 80 solve the equation?

I know that $x^{\Phi(81)}=x^{54}=1 (mod 81)$ but that doesn't help.
Plus I tried calculating for small number like 1,2,3 yet nothing worked...

**Note:** if 54 was multiplication of 7 then I could solve it easily as I know that $x^{54}=x^{7k}={x^{k}}^{7}$ so the final answer would be $4*x^k (mod 81)$

---

**My answer to 1:**

I know that $2^54 = 1 (mod 81)$ so $2^56 = 4 (mod 81)$ which means: ${2^{8}}^{7} = 4 (mod 81)$ and the answer is $2^8 (mod 81)$ which is equal to 13.

But what about 2? I have no idea at all...

Comment: Since $81 = 3^4$, you can reduce the equation modulo $3$ to get $x^7 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$, so $x \equiv 1 \pmod 3$, hence $x$ has the form $3 y + 1$, cutting your search space by $2 / 3$. Now, substitute $x = 3 y + 1$ in the original equation and reduce modulo $9$ to produce a restriction on $y$, etc.

Comment: @Algo FYI, there's what I consider to be a simpler approach for your particular problem. Note an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24x%5E7%5Cequiv%204%5Cpmod%7B81%7D%24&p=1) comes up with [how to solve this kind of modular arithmetic problems with exponents?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3465718), where you can use a similar approach to what's in its answer. First, though, note that, using [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function), $\varphi(81)=81\left(1-\frac{1}{3}\right)=54$, not $78$ as you indicate. ...

Comment: (cont.) Thus, using $4=2^2$, we can get by taking both sides to the power $27$ that $x^{27}\equiv 1\pmod{81}$, then we can take both sides of the original congruence equation to the power of $4$ to finish off.

Comment: Since $\gcd(7, 54)=1$,  there can't be a $7^{th}$ root of unity $\pmod {81}$, so every residue prime to $81$ has a unique $7^{th}$ root.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Thanks that did help a lot, please see my answer and let me know if it's correct now :), can you please help with 2 how can I count all possible answers without testing every value?

Comment: @Algo You're welcome. You've correctly determined $x\equiv 13\pmod{81}$ is *one* solution. Note [lulu's comment](/questions/4745057/how-to-solve-x7-4-pmod81-without-guessing?noredirect=1#comment10065877_4745057), and also [cubesteak's answer](/a/4745074), both indicate how to show there's just one solution. Alternatively, my suggestion, from my earlier comment, is that $x^{28}\equiv 4^4\equiv 13\pmod{81}$, so $x^{27}\equiv 1\pmod{81}$ means $x\equiv 13\pmod{81}$, with this method explicitly showing there is just one solution. In either case, this means you can then answer your question $2$.

Comment: Just as a matter of notation, exponentiation associates on the right. That is, when you write ${2^{8}}^{7}$, it means ${2^{(8^7)}}$, not $({2^{8}})^{7}$.

Comment: See the [Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3188192/242) in the linked dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that $x^{54}\equiv1\pmod{81}$.  What if we use that by exponentiating both sides of the equivalence?  First, solve $7k\equiv1\pmod{54}$.  We get $k\equiv1\pmod2$ and $k\equiv4\pmod{27}$, so $k\equiv31\pmod{54}$.  So
$$x^{31(7)}\equiv4^{31}\pmod{81}$$
$$x^{4(54)+1}\equiv2^{62}\pmod{81}$$
$$x\equiv2^8\pmod{81}$$

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).